# Why does tcolorbox adds vertical space?

Tags: tcolorbox, exsheets

I use some `tcolorbox`es in the solution section of a math paper. For some reason there is some vertical space added.

How can I align the solution number with the top of the tcolorbox?
(The red boxes in the following picture are the added space I don't want.)

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{hugeIndent}{default}{
  runin = true,
  attach = {main[r,vc]number[l,vc](-3em,0pt)}
}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings=hugeIndent,
  question/pre-hook=\begin{addmargin}[3em]{0cm},
  question/post-hook=\end{addmargin},
  solution/pre-hook=\begin{addmargin}[3em]{0cm},
  solution/post-hook=\end{addmargin},
  counter-within={section},
  counter-format=ch.se.qu[1]
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \part{EXCERCISES}
    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}[ID=111]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
\tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam
]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm, baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{
    Bad aligned!
}
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}[ID=121]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
\tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam
]
{
    I'm a bad
}
{
    aligned solution.
}
        \end{solution}

        \begin{question}[ID=122]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm a perfectly aligned solution.
        \end{solution}

  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \part{SOLUTIONS}

    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={111}]

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={121}]

       \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={122}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `tcolorbox` but I believe you want its option `nobeforeafter`

Comment: Typically a tcolorbox starts a new paragraph. See the description of the before key. So you either need to avoid this or add some negative space with `enlarge top initially by=\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax`.

Comment: @Ulrike, if I add `enlarge top initially by=\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax` to the solution 1.1.1 it works fine, but for solution 1.2.1 not. Why is that?

Comment: The value gets negative. `before skip=\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax` is better. And add \strut at the begin of text content. (But it is possible that the solution and content get separated by a page break, didn't check).

Comment: It works great (no page break!), if I use `before skip=\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax` and `\strut` (in both columns of solution 1.2.1). Should I use `\strut` even in both columns of solution 1.1.1 or only in the right column? PS: I would be glad to accept this as an answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician I will do it, but later this day.

Comment: That seemed to be an extremely long day. ;-)