# exsheets: headings and page break

Tags: page-breaking, exsheets

If a picture doesn't fit on a page, it's printed one the following page, while it's heading (in my case just the exercise number) is printed on the page before.

> Is it possible to print the heading and the picture on the same page?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{hugeIndent}{default}{
  runin = true,
  attach = {main[r,vc]number[l,vc](-3em,0pt)}
}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings=hugeIndent,
  question/pre-hook=\begin{addmargin}[3em]{0cm},
  question/post-hook=\end{addmargin},
  solution/pre-hook=\begin{addmargin}[3em]{0cm},
  solution/post-hook=\end{addmargin},
  counter-within={section},
  counter-format=ch.se.qu[1]
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \part{EXCERCISES}
    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}[ID=111]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
    \tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam,
    before skip=\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax
]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm, baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{
    description
}
        \end{solution}


  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \part{SOLUTIONS}

    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={111,111}]

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

        \printsolutions[byID={111,111}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've added a before skip to the tcolorbox which also inserts a possible break point...

Comment: Even without `before skip` there is a break point - you can see this if you delete the `before skip` line and the _lorem ipsum_ text.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30734/how-make-sure-two-elements-stay-on-the-same-page

Comment: Then the tcolorbox probably starts a new paragraph…

Comment: Does this help: remove the `before skip` option and add `nobeforeafter,  box align=top`

Comment: @clemens: Your solution eliminates the page break. That's great. But without the `before skip` option I don't know how to align the heading next to the picture. Related: [How to align heading and tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316969/101831)

Comment: @clemens: I'll accept your answer as solution. The alignment is another question. Thanks again for your help!