# Why is some vertical space added around text in a tcolorbox while textcolor or itemize are active?

Tags: color, tcolorbox, itemize, vertical-spacing

If I remove the textcolor specification (and the corresponding 2 curly braces), the useless space around "someItem" disappears.
If I replace the "\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}" bloc by just a text, the useless space around "someItem" disappears.

Why are there these differences?
I tried to remove all the blanks in my LaTeX source, because I thought there were causing some problems, but that didn't help.

Is it related to the notion of "vertical mode" (that I don't understand yet, but someone mentioned it in one my other posts about unwanted spaces)?

I saw some posts with similar problems (for example: [Why does tcolorbox adds vertical space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316969/why-does-tcolorbox-adds-vertical-space)), maybe their solution would work, but I still wouldn't understand what textcolor or itemize are breaking in my MWE...

I'm using LuaLaTex, but the result in the same on this online service:
https://latex.net/texlive/

In fact, I don't really need a color for my text. I just put it to play with fonts in one of my documents.  So I'll just remove the "textcolor" and my document will be ok, but I would still like to understand what's going on!

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\begin{document}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[notitle]%
{\textcolor{blue}{%
\begin{itemize}%
\item{someItem}%
\end{itemize}%
}}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{document}%
```

[image: unwanted_vertical_space_around_text]

Answer (score 1):

Well color can affect spacing as it adds whatsits. And if you use `\textcolor` instead of `\color` you additionally start a paragraph. With lualatex can use use luacolor, that avoids parts of the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{luacolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[notitle]
\begin{itemize}
\item{someItem}
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[notitle]
\color{blue}
\begin{itemize}
\item{someItem}
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[notitle]
\textcolor{blue}
{\begin{itemize}
\item{someItem}
\end{itemize}}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[notitle]
\leavevmode
\begin{itemize}
\item{someItem}
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

### with luacolor

[image]

### without luacolor

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use `\color`.
I'm still not very experienced with `LaTeX`, so would you say that, for experienced `LaTeX` users, whatsits problems/surprises...:
- are common, or are they more frequent with people like me who learn by themselves, and/or stumble on these problems because they don't have any filter, they don't know what's useful, what's dangerous, etc.?
- are easily solved (like using `\color` instead of `\textcolor`), or are they mostly tricky?